# Explain the output — I don't understand how the value of i will be changed

Tags: c, operators

```
/*how will the value of i be changed in output*/

void main()
{
    int i = 150;
    char c = i;
    i = c;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: how the value of i will be change..?

Comment: Edit the Question rather than leave comments that have additional questions or information. See [ask]. Also edit your question to ensure correct use of tags, and an example of the output your are seeing would be helpful for others trying to answer your question.

Comment: no duplicates? no time for diggin some ATM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `char` can only hold one byte of data, -128 to 127, so storing a value of 150 in it causes sign overflow, giving a negative result.

Sign overflow results in undefined behavior, however, what often happens is :

Up to the max positive value of 127, everything is ok.

When 128 is assigned, the sign bit gets set and the reported value flips to -128.

For every value of 1 you go above this value, the value will also increase.

So, in your case assigning 150, at 128 the bit flips, and you still have 22 left (150 - 128), so the final value could be -106 (-128 + 22).

And this is, in fact, the result I get on windows with Visual Studio if I try it.  But again, this is undefined behavior, so there is no guarantee what you system will do when you overflow the sign bit.

Comment: and how the negative result can be calulated? or sign overflow work?

Comment: The standard says that plain `char` has the same range as either `signed char` or `unsigned char` but is distinct from both. If the plain `char` type has the same range as `signed char`, the range mentioned is the normal range, but it need not be so.  OTOH, the question would probably not be asked were it not so.

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed that `char` could be signed or unsigned, but couldn't find any other specific info related to that.

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour here. *Out of range assignment* is not a case of overflow.  Overflow is when the result of an *arithmetic operation* would exceed the bounds of the type of the result.  Furthermore, some systems have `char` as 0-255,  or a larger range even, in fact there are probably more such systems in existence than not.

Comment: See [C11 §6.2.5 Types ¶3-6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5).  See also [Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1).  See also [§6.2.6 Representations of types](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6) and [§6.2.6.2 Integer types](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2).